# Unable to upload widget to Wirecloud instances in private server

Tags: widget, fiware, fiware-wirecloud

We have downloaded and installed a running instance of Wirecloud in our company server following the steps at:

https://conwet.fi.upm.es/wirecloud/install

We created the instance using the **--quick-start** command to try the instance, and ran wirecloud using the Django internal web server with the following command:

$ python manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8080 --insecure

We are able to enter the instance, and move around the enviroment, but we have encountered a problem when we try to upload a widget to our local workspace. After I search for the widget in my computer (previously downloaded from the Fi-lab marketplace), we get the next message:

**Error adding packaged resource: Internal Server Error.**

We also tried to download the zip file of the widget from github, unzip it and recompress it as a wgt file (compress as a zip but changing the extension to .wgt) and we get the same answer from our wirecloud instance; but if we try to upload the same package to the instance in fi-lab, it uploads successfully.

We don't know if it's because of the quick-start installation we made or if we have to modify something from our widget files in order to be able to upload it to our local instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solved**

The problem was in the config.xml file: the name of the attributes and the structure of the widgets unable to upload were different from the template of the config.xml file posted at the users guide.

After changing it to follow the structure of the template it works fine.

My widget example was the NGSI Updater. The thing is that it uploads perfectly in the instance at FiLab, even though the config.xml file had a different structure from the one of the template; but it encounters an error when uploading it to the Wirecloud local instance at my server.